# Word "Find" search to find sentences with too many words

Tags: microsoft-word, search, automation, text-editing

I would like to find sentences with more than 25 words, as in, more than 25 words between two periods or any ending point of the sort (.?!) while ignoring commas.

Is there any capability that can do this automatically in a 100+ page document?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to understand that periods
(and question marks and exclamation marks)
in the text can confuse things. 
For example, by your definition (“words between two periods
or any ending point of the sort (.?!) …”), the following:

> Avid fans (they like to call themselves Whovians)
>   of the long-running British science fiction television series, *Dr. Who*,
>   will tell you that the name of the main character
>   is not “Doctor Who” but rather, simply, “The Doctor”.

counts as two sentences, each of which has fewer than 25 words,
because of the period in “*Dr. Who*”. 
For more discussion on and examples of the difficulty
of really *really* breaking English text into sentences,
see [How to put sentences on separate lines on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190985/23408).

Given that you don’t expect the solution
to handle intra-sentence periods correctly,
and assuming that words are separated by spaces (not tabs or line breaks),
the following search pattern:

```
<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @<[!.?\!]@ @
```

should find sentences longer than 25 words,
using “wildcard” search mode in Word.

This is simply `<[!.?\!]@ @` repeated 25_times.

- `<` matches the beginning of a word. 
  We probably don’t need this.
- `[!…]` is a character group — one character that’s not in the brackets.
- `[!.?\!]` is any character other than `.`, `?` or `!`. 
  This matches letters, numerals, and other punctuation
  (e.g., quotes, apostrophes, commas, semicolons, etc.) 
  Note that the `!` inside the brackets must be escaped.
- `@` means one or more of the previous expression,
  so `[!.?\!]@` matches a word (possibly including non-terminal punctuation.
- `@` is one or more spaces.

So `<[!.?\!]@ @` matches a word
(including commas, etc., but not periods, etc.)
and the following space(s).

I tried to use `(…){25,}`, but I couldn’t get it to work.